# Why did Snell's Law give me a negative angle?

Tags: waves, speed-of-light, refraction

Problem.
1.33sin(80degrees)=1.0003sin(theta)

answer=-26.15 degrees.

I was wondering why Snell's Law gave me a negative angle.
My reasoning was because the angle fell below the x-axis, and can't think of anything else. You have 90 degrees going upwards, and -90 degrees going downwards. Is there more to it?

Thank you.

edit:

theta = arcsin(1.333sin(80degrees)/1.0003)
theta = -26.15

Comment: The left side of your equation evaluates to about 1.3. I'm not sure how you managed to find any angle, positive or negative, with that sine.

Comment: I don't see your point. I edited the bottom of the question. You can clearly get an angle from this equation. Edit: I tried it on the calculator and I am getting an error. On google I got that answer.

Comment: I am getting an error because sine has to be between +-1?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out for me. I figured it out. Thank you M. Enns

Comment: A complex number can have a sine with the real part greater than 1. Whatever you did on google, you probably got either the real part the imaginary part, or the absolute value of a complex number. Take home message: search engines aren't magic, you still need to understand enough to ask them sensible questions!

Answer (score 3):

The incident angle is larger than the critical angle so that a total reflection occurs.
$$n_1 \sin(\theta_1)=n_2 \sin(\theta_2)$$
In your problem,$n_1=1.33,n_2=1$. Take $\theta_2=90^{\circ}$
$$\theta_{1critical}=\arcsin(\frac{n_2}{n_1})=48.8^{\circ}$$
And $80^{\circ}$ is much larger that this so we have a total reflection and there will be no refraction light.